# check ip is present and update iptables openvpn

Tags: iptables, bash, openvpn, scripting, grep

I want to check that the ip is present within the ccd folder and push the ip route to the FORWARDING chain in the iptables. Im new to bash scripting and need a little help finishing this script.

client file in /etc/openvpn/ccd :

```
ifconfig-push 10.8.0.45 255.255.255.0
push 'route 10.10.0.45'
```

I need to grep `10.8.0.45 & 10.10.0.45`

and push those routes in the iptables.
e.g

```
iptables -A FORWARD -s 10.8.0.45 -d 10.10.0.45 -j ACCEPT
```

client-connect /etc/openvpn/on_connect.sh

script I need help with 'grep' or 'awk'

```
static_ip=  grep "^push \"route" | grep "^'" | cut -f2 -d" "

ip_destination=grep "^push \"route" | grep "^'" | cut -f3 -d" "
```

> ```
> #!/usr/bin/env bash
> #
> #  Add iptables rules based on CCD client config.
> #
>
> CCD_DIR="/etc/openvpn/ccd"
> # iptables rule comment - the disconnect script will
> # remove all strings matching this pattern
> RULE_COMMENT="OVPN_"$common_name
> static_ip=grep..
> ip_destination=grep..
>
>
>
> if [ -f $CCD_DIR/$common_name ]; then
>   sudo iptables -A FORWARD -s $static_ip -d ip_destination -j ACCEPT
> fi
>
> exit 0
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to grep for files in the `openvpn` directory, `grep -R /etc/openvpn/ccd -E '10.(8|45).0.45'`
To see if this returns success, you can do:

```
 if grep -qRE /etc/openvpn/ccd '10\.(8|45)\.0\.45' ; then
    : # do somethig
 fi
```

HTH.

P.S. I wanted to add comments to ask for more details, but I dont have enough points to comment